# Is it a variable or an object? Im very confused

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main (int argc, char * argv[])
    {

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString *str = @"Programming is fun";
        NSLog (@"%@", str);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the line

```
NSString *str = @"Programming is fun";
```

the constant string object Programming is fun is assigned to the `NSString` **variable** `str`. Its value is then displayed using `NSLog` .

The `NSLog` format characters `%@` can be used to display not just `NSString` **objects**, but other objects as well.

/*********/

The previous paragraph was from a book I read, what is really confusing to me is why is he keep using the words `variable` and `objects` interchangeably? are objects and varaibles the same thing? so far this is the only confusing part  about obj-c to me.

please explain, thank you

Comment: So please, if you solve your doubt, would be a good practice select the right answer to consider the question/answer topic closed. Thank you.

Comment: To be brutally honest, you should have a good comprehension of these terms before you even begin working with Objective-C.  One should learn C or Java first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `object` is an **instance** of a **class**. Something that is **allocated** in memory.

A `variable` is a **name** which you use to **access something** like an **object** (`NSString` for example) or a **primitive** (`int` for example).

In your case so your **object is an instance** of `NSString`, that contains `@"Programming is fun"`:

```
NSString *str = @"Programming is fun";
```

The variable to access that object is `str`.

Comment: 1st of all thank you for you help... I read a lot tutorials/books/articles about objective-c, I never heard that I need a variable to access object, Im still confused, can you give me an article about that please?

Comment: ...i don't guess you will read about this on some article because is obvious. How do you call your friend if you haven't his number?..i don't think you will se an article on how to call LOL :D

Comment: NSString *myString is myString an object or variable?

Comment: here is another example i dont understand from the same book: "if your class has an NSArray object as one of its instance variables"

Comment: Man no worries about this!! Try ti understand: an object is pointed from a variable, so that variable is also called an object at the end because point to the object..

Comment: I think i need to reread the chapter about classes and variables, thank you very for your time

Comment: Further, it needs to be noted that the special type of variable used to access an object is called a "pointer".  (In Java it's called a "reference".)